# Circular application flow - Need Idea

Tags: ios, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller

I have an screen (My Profile) which can be accessed from two paths:

- Login -> Content -> Profile
- Login -> Register -> Profile.

In both paths, view's are shown with:

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController...];
```

But my problem is, after the user registers and completes his profile, it should go "Back" to the Content view. (Obviously it won't work with navigation controller stack, since Content isn't in the navigation controller).

My question is, what suggestions do you have?

PS: I know this isn't an actual question, but I've been thinking about this for a few hours now and I didn't come up with anything. Maybe some of you have had to deal with similar cases.

Edit: Basically the question can be generalised to:
**How do you deal with a circular application flow?**

Edit: I've solved this by pushing from Register to Content and then Profile in viewWillAppeare  without animation (so what I need is in the stack), but I'm still interested in dealing with circular application flows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would by to change [UINavigationController viewControllers].

So after you end your registration you can do something like

```
ContentVC *content = [[ContentVC alloc] init];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:content]];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Push Contentview controller after profile complated in second case , while in first case you have already pushing it.

Answer (score 0):

1)Make your Login viewController the rootController of the a UINavigationController.

2)From Login you can Push Content ViewController

3)From Content VC you can push to Profile VC.

Now if you want to get back to Content from profile do this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And if you want o get back from Profile directly to Login do this:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you do not want the navigation bar you can hide the bar.

**Update**

Take a different approach, other than the navigation controller stack:

1) Make a controller class with a 2 functions:

```
-(void)loadViewControllerWithIndex:(int)index;
```

and

```
-(void)unLoadCurentViewController;
```

2) You can call these functions and load and unload the view controllers from a this controller class.

3) So you initially load this class and import file in this class of other view controllers. You can take a UIViewController object topViewController, so that you can you can keep a track on which controller is currently displayed and it will help when you want to unload a controller.

4) In load controller with Index function you can add the controller view and in unload you may remove them.

Comment: That's a no brainer... It's not what I have a problem with. The problem is, the program flow is circular (Login -> Register -> Profile, then the pop from Profile should lead me to Content not to Register).